# Java org.w3c.dom - Recursively find and return an attribute value in a NodeList

Tags: java, dom, recursion

I am currently parsing an XML response from a web service.  It returns a finite number of `<result>` elements.  I am currently iterating through a `NodeList` of such results.

While I iterate through this, sometimes I need to find the value of an attribute that exists in each `<result>` element.  In that case, I want to call a method that traverses through all of the child nodes (and potentially the children's children, etc.) and returns the attribute's value.

I have attempted to do this recursively:

```
private String findAttrInChildren(Element element, String tag) {
    if (!element.getAttribute(tag).isEmpty()) {
        return element.getAttribute(tag);
    }

    NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0, len = children.getLength(); i < len; i++) {
        if (children.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element childElement = (Element) children.item(i);
            return findAttrInChildren(childElement, tag);
        }
    }

    // We didn't find it, return null
    return null;
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working.  Is recursion the best approach here?  I think the fact that I want to return a value at the end is messing me up somewhere along the line, rather than implementing a `void` recursive method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You leave the recursion too early. Given

```
if (children.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element childElement = (Element) children.item(i);
    return findAttrInChildren(childElement, tag);
}
```

this will end the recursive search at the first child element - regardless if the child or one of its descendants has the attribute or not.

So test if the returned attribute is not null:

```
if (children.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element childElement = (Element) children.item(i);
    String attr = findAttrInChildren(childElement, tag);
    if (attr != null)
        return attr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know your question was answered and you got an answer that works but you can actually make your code a little better. You should avoid 2 exit points and have 1 instead and always avoid null. So to cater these both I am going to modify your code and provide you a new one. I hope you understand the changes. I am using Optional to avoid null and make your code a little more readable and understandable.

```
private static Optional<String> findAttributeInChildren(Element element, String tag) {
        Optional<String> attr = Optional.empty();
        if (!element.getAttribute(tag).isEmpty()) {
            attr = Optional.of(element.getAttribute(tag));

        } else {
            NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
            int len = children.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; (i < len) && (!attr.isPresent()); i++) {
                if (children.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element childElement = (Element) children.item(i);
                    attr = findAttributeInChildren(childElement, tag);
                }
            }
        }

        return attr;
    }
```

And if you want to check whether your code has some value or not you just do;

```
findAttributeInChildren(x,y).isPresent()
```

rather than

```
findAttributeInChildren(x,y) == null
```